# Is the xgboost documentation wrong ? (early stopping rounds and best and last iteration)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

here below is a question about xgboost early stopping rounds parameter and how it does, or does not, give the best iteration when it is the reason why the fit ends.

In xgboost documentation, one can see in the scikit learn api section ([link](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBRegressor.fit)) that when the fit stops due to the early stopping rounds parameter:

> Activates early stopping. Validation error needs to decrease at least every "early_stopping_rounds" round(s) to continue training. Requires at least one item in evals. If there’s more than one, will use the last. Returns the model from the last iteration (not the best one).

When reeding this, it seems that the model returned, in this case, is not the best one but the last one. To access the best one when predict, it says, it is possible to call the predict using the ntree_limit parameter with the  bst.best_ntree_limit given at the end of the fit.

In this sense, it should work the same way as the train of xgboost since the fit of the scikitlearn api seems to be only an embedding of the train and others.

It is wiedly discussed here [stack overflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40500638/xgboost-cv-and-best-iteration) or here [another discussion](https://machinelearningmastery.com/avoid-overfitting-by-early-stopping-with-xgboost-in-python/)

But when I tried to address this problem and check how it worked with my data, I did not find the behavior that I thought I should have. In fact the behavior I encountered was not at all the one discribed in those discussions and documentation.

I call a fit this way:

reg = xgb.XGBRegressor(n_jobs=6, n_estimators = 100, max_depth= 5)

```
reg.fit(
   X_train, 
   y_train, 
   eval_metric='rmse',    
   eval_set=[(X_train, y_train), (X_valid, y_valid)],
   verbose=True,
   early_stopping_rounds = 6)
```

and here is what I get in the end:

```
[71]    validation_0-rmse:1.70071   validation_1-rmse:1.9382
[72]    validation_0-rmse:1.69806   validation_1-rmse:1.93825
[73]    validation_0-rmse:1.69732   validation_1-rmse:1.93803
Stopping. Best iteration:
[67]    validation_0-rmse:1.70768   validation_1-rmse:1.93734
```

and when I check the values of the validation I used :

```
y_pred_valid = reg.predict(X_valid)
y_pred_valid_df = pd.DataFrame(y_pred_valid)
sqrt(mse(y_valid, y_pred_valid_df[0]))
```

I get

> 1.9373418403889535

If the fit had return the last iteration instead of the best one it should have given an rmse around 1.93803 but it gave an rmse at 1.93734, exactly the best score.

I checked again by two ways:
[Edit]  I've edited the code below according to @Eran Moshe answer

```
y_pred_valid = reg.predict(X_valid, ntree_limit=reg.best_ntree_limit)
y_pred_valid_df = pd.DataFrame(y_pred_valid)
sqrt(mse(y_valid, y_pred_valid_df[0]))
```

> 1.9373418403889535

and even if I call the fit (knowing the best iter is the 67th) with only 68 estimators so that I'm sure the last one is the best one:

```
reg = xgb.XGBRegressor(n_jobs=6, n_estimators = 68, max_depth= 5)

reg.fit(
   X_train, 
   y_train, 
   eval_metric='rmse',    
   eval_set=[(X_train, y_train), (X_valid, y_valid)],
   verbose=True,
   early_stopping_rounds = 6)
```

the result is the same:

> 1.9373418403889535

So that seems to lead to the idea that, unlike the documentation, and those numerous discussions about it, tell, the fit of xgboost, when stopped by the early stopping round parameter, does give the best iter, not the last one.

Am I wrong, if so, where, and how do you explain the behavior I met ?

Thanks for the attention

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think, it is not wrong, but *inconsistent*.

The documentation of the `predict` method is correct (e.g. see [here](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBRegressor.predict)). To bee 100% sure it is better to look into the code: [xgb github](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/48dddfd635b0fa6575b9934334254533e5d8708d/python-package/xgboost/sklearn.py#L767-L768), so `predict` behaves as is stated in it's documentation, but the `fit` documentation is outdated. Please, post it as an issue on XGB github and either they will fix the docs or you will and will become an XGB contributer :)

Comment: As a matter of fact, I did post an issue on this matter on XGB github but until now there is not any answer to it. Wait & see

Comment: FYI, I made a pullrequest to correct the documentation and it was accepted. See pull request #3967 : https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/pull/3967

Answer (score 1):

You have a code error there.

Notice how

```
reg.predict(X_valid, ntree_limit=reg.best_ntree_limit)
```

Should be

```
y_pred_valid = reg.predict(X_valid, ntree_limit=reg.best_ntree_limit)
```

So in fact you're making the same comparison, when calculating

```
sqrt(mse(y_valid, y_pred_valid_df[0]))
```

---

Xgboost is working just as you've read. `early_stopping_round = x` will train until it didn't improve for `x` consecutive rounds.

And when predicting with `ntree_limit=y` it'll use ONLY the first `y` Boosters.

Comment: There was indeed a code error where you mentioned it and I corrected it but it  does not change the question I asked. When I predict wihtout using the ntree_limit parameter, it still gives the best answer. Why ?

Comment: No it's not. I've tested it myself many times and you are plain wrong. But I'm using xgboost.train and not the XGBRegressor wrapper. Maybe test direct usage of xgboost without the wrap-around

Comment: Yes it is ! I asked specificaly with the wrap-around and the documentation confirms that it should give the last not the best iter even with the wrap-around. Thus the question.

Comment: I don't think they'll use different functionality for the wrap-around way.. it's probably inherit the same calculations the native xgboost package do. Maybe you should go look into the code..

Answer (score 1):

To be more precise, and accordingly to @Mykhailo Lisovyi, the documentation is quite inconsistent in the scikit-learn api section since the fit paragraph tells that when early stopping rounds occures, the last iteration is returned not the best one, but the predict paragraph tells that when the predict is called without ntree_limit specified, then ntree_limit is equals to best_ntree_limit.

Thus, when reading the fit part, one could think that it is needed to specify what is the best iter when calling the predict, but when reading the predict part, then the best iter is given by default, it is the last iter that you have to specify if needed.

I posted an issue on the github of xgboost.... wait & see

[UPDATE] : the pull request has been accepted : [link](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/pull/3967)